# flink on k8s, when task is executed, only jobmanager.log/taskmanager.log files are available, .err and.out files are not available

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

When Flink version 1.12.7 is running on k8s, the default local flink path contains only jobmanager.log or taskmanager.log logs. When I was deployed on yarn, jobmanager.log, jobmanager.err, and jobmanager.out logs were generated. I want to know the fault.

Fumbled, found that after watching the source code in the flink runtime project under the Bootstrap class, have a getTaskManagerShellCommand method
The method appears to be configured with a startup command, which contains a piece of code:

```
startCommandValues.put(
                "redirects",
                "1> "
                        + logDirectory
                        + "/taskmanager.out "
                        + "2> "
                        + logDirectory
                        + "/taskmanager.err");
```

Redirects standard output to the taskmanager.out file in the specified log directory, and standard error output to the taskmanager.err file in the specified log directory. Further found that the flink yarn Utils class project, a createTaskExecutorContext method, this method invokes the obtained getTaskManagerShellCommand launchCommand above, And in debug mode, you can print out the launchCommand, which I printed as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiG1e.png)

There is a command that redirects the standard output and standard error output.

But when deploying flink to k8s, since the above log debug log is not printed in the k8s source code, I also used the KubernetesUtils method under the flink kubernetes project, Also found the corresponding getCommonStartCommand method, but in this method, flink1.11 version has the above redirect command statement, but after 1.12 version I found that this command is missing?

Is it because flink 1.12 did not have this redirection command so that when you deploy to k8s, you only have a.log file instead of.err and.out files?

Has anyone experienced a similar problem? I invite you to share your views. Thanks very much.

I expect to have taskmanager.log, taskmanager.err, and taskmanager.out files when the task is running on k8s, just like on yarn。

Has anyone experienced a similar problem? How is it solved?